# Showing that $0 < \cos (\theta)<\frac {\sin (\theta)}{\theta}<\frac {1}{\cos(\theta)} $

Tags: trigonometry

$$0 < \cos (\theta)<\frac {\sin (\theta)}{\theta}<\frac {1}{\cos(\theta)} $$
for $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$.